# Как подружить GitLab с Apache?

Tags: ubuntu, apache, gitlab

Установил GitLab на Ubuntu Server 14.04 по инструкции с оф. сайта:
https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/#ubuntu1404
По-умолчанию гитлаб использует Nginx, пытался подружить его с Apache по различным инструкциям (например, http://ryansechrest.com/2015/08/use-apache-instead-of-built-in-nginx-in-gitlab-ce/ ), но ничего не выходит. Кто-нибудь может помочь и описать пошаговый алгоритм привязки GitLab к Apache?

Comment: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/tree/master/web-server/apache